# What does the score in the tag mean?

Tags: support, tag-score

This is my reputation on Stack Overflow:

[image]

But I am not sure about how the score in the tags is calculated. Here for example in Java I have:

> 712 java x 1063

I know pretty well that reputation points changes according to this criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation, but

> 712 java x 1063

So what does 1063 mean?

Comment: The second is the number of your answers. The first is the net number of upvotes on those questions.

Comment: Your [user page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/982161/Φxocę-웃-Пepeúpa-ツ) contains exactly that number as "Number of posts". Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated

Comment: Surely if that's the number of posts then it should be "earned 712 reputation _over_ 1063 posts", not times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hover the numbers and a tooltip explains:

> Asked 7 non-wiki questions with a total score of 5. Gave 1056 non-wiki answers with a total score of 712.

> 1063 posts in the java tag

So the first number is the score of your non-wiki answers, the second one is the number of posts.

Comment: Basically,number of posts = non wiki questions + non wiki answers.